# Can't run apps installed from an appx package - error 0x800704cf

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-store-app, windows-store

When running apps that were installed with Windows's default App installer (Appx and msixbundle files), Trying to run the installed applications fails and the following error (Error 0x800704cf) appears:

[image]

The packages I have installed and failed are:

- Windows Terminal Preview msixbundle from github releases page
- Ubuntu, Kali, Debian for WSL from [Microsoft WSL Support Page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual)

My machine is offline, so my only option for installing these applications is with the the appx files.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround that works.
For the Linix distros, I found that when trying to run the executable from the specified folder (under WindowsApps), I get a permession denied error instead of the network error. I copied the whole folder to a different place, ran the executable and everything works fine.
For the Windows terminal, I tried running the executable, and got an error the vclibs_140 dll was not found (even though I installed it). I added the DLL's path to the System PATH variable, and now I can run the executable.
Running both apps from the start menu still don't work and cause a network error, but at least I can run them from their executables.